# Nestjs swagger issue

Tags: node.js, swagger, nestjs

I'm trying to add swagger to my nestjs app, and this is an error that I'm getting.

```
(node:78477) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at lodash_1.mapValues.param (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/explorers/api-parameters.explorer.js:34:20)
    at /Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
    at /Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseForOwn (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
    at exploreApiReflectedParametersMetadata (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/explorers/api-parameters.explorer.js:33:41)
    at exports.exploreApiParametersMetadata (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/explorers/api-parameters.explorer.js:11:33)
    at explorers.reduce (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:55:45)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at lodash_1.mapValues (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:54:97)
    at /Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13401:38
    at /Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4905:15
    at baseForOwn (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:2990:24)
    at Function.mapValues (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:7)
    at MapIterator.denormalizedPaths.metadataScanner.scanFromPrototype.name [as iteratee] (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:54:45)
    at MapIterator.next (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/iterare/lib/map.js:13:39)
    at FilterIterator.next (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/iterare/lib/filter.js:12:34)
    at IteratorWithOperators.next (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/iterare/lib/iterate.js:21:28)
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at IteratorWithOperators.toArray (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/iterare/lib/iterate.js:180:22)
    at MetadataScanner.scanFromPrototype (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/core/metadata-scanner.js:11:14)
    at SwaggerExplorer.generateDenormalizedDocument (/Users/anna/SoFetch/node_modules/@nestjs/swagger/dist/swagger-explorer.js:48:56)
(node:78477) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:78477) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I narrowed down the problem to the controller. Here it is:

```
constructor(@Inject('UserService') private  readonly  userService:  UserService) {}
    @Post('login')
    async login(@Body() login: LoginModel): Promise<any> {
      return this.userService.login(login.username, login.password);
    }  

    @Post('register/customer')
    async registerCustomer(@Body() customer: CustomerRegisterModel): Promise<any> {
        if(customer.password !== customer.confirmPassword) {
            throw new NotAcceptableException();
        }
      return this.userService.createCustomer(customer.name, customer.username, customer.email, customer.password);  
    }

    @Post('register/technician')
    async registerTechnician(@Body() technician: TechnicianRegistrationModel): Promise<any> {
        return this.userService.createTechnician(technician.name, technician.username, technician.email, technician.password, technician.location); 
    }
```

this controller is not working but when I add a simple method like this:

```
    @Get()
     Hello(login: string):string{
      return "helloworld"
    }
```

it works.

It seems like I have a problem with @Body @Query attributes. But I can't manage to find it.

Anyone else had the same problem?

Comment: I don't see the code for swagger in your implementation.

Comment: I was using the standard thing from the nest.js recipies documentation. added `const options = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Cats example')
    .setDescription('The cats API description')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addTag('cats')
    .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);` code to main.ts

Comment: are your `TechnicianRegistrationModel` , `CustomerRegisterModel` and `LoginModel` interfaces or classes?  : )

Comment: those are classes. The moment I comment the Post methods the swagger workds.

Comment: Could you share the way you define these model classes please ? At least the way you use swagger annotations within them

Comment: import { ApiModelProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";


export class ChangePasswordModel {
    @ApiModelProperty()
    readonly username: string;
    @ApiModelProperty()
    readonly password: string;
    @ApiModelProperty()
    readonly confirmPassword: string;
}

Comment: my swagger was working before I added the methods with @Body()

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after adding the `@Body() ...` parameter decorator, and in the end, I resolved it by replacing my `tsconfig.json` file with the following.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

What happened: An error was thrown in the swagger file `parameter-metadata-accessor.js`, in particular, the `types` array was undefined, so when `parametersWithType` accessed it, it threw.

```js
class ParameterMetadataAccessor {
    explore(instance, prototype, method) {
        const types = Reflect.getMetadata(constants_1.PARAMTYPES_METADATA, instance, method.name);
        const routeArgsMetadata = Reflect.getMetadata(constants_1.ROUTE_ARGS_METADATA, instance.constructor, method.name) || {};
        const parametersWithType = lodash_1.mapValues(reverse_object_keys_util_1.reverseObjectKeys(routeArgsMetadata), (param) => ({
            type: types[param.index],
            name: param.data,
            required: true
        }));
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Basically what is really needed is `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` as described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata (along with `experimentalDecorators`)